# How can I get the item being removed when CacheItemUpdateCallback is called

Tags: c#, caching

I want to avoid an item being removed from cache when expire in SOME OCASIONS

If i understand how CacheItemUpdateCallback works, i need to asign to expensiveObject the new object, in my case: the old one.
But i cant access the item with HttpContext.Current.Cache[key],

my question: how to access the old item? or in other words, How prevent this item being removed in the first place?

Comment: dont' use cache. use application variable: HttpContext.Current.Application[key]

Comment: Can't do that. i dont want to loose all the Caching features. I just need to prevent this IN SOME OCASIONS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the HttpRuntime to access the Cache.